# CSS3 ellipsis, centered text and responsive design

Tags: css, ellipsis

There's a billion of tutorials, but none have worked for me unfortunately.
I need some artistnames to be in the header, centered, but with a css ellipsis, so very long names gets the "..." and will be truncated.

You can see the design here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/mobile/artistchannel.php
Remember to resize your browser window.

Its meant for mobiles, so I cannot have any fixed withs and it should work with all kinds of mobile screensizes. I can make the ellipsis work, but then the text is no longer centered. 
Any clue on how to do this best? I would really like to avoid any javascript as performance is highly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the rules for `h1` with `overflow` & `text-overflow`.

```
.header h1, .headerwhite h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 49px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;/* generates dots if text on one single line and truncated */
    overflow: hidden;/* triggers text-oveflow and mids floatting elements */
    white-space: nowrap;/* keep text on a single line to trigger text-overflow; */
    display: block;/* reset to basic behavior of h1 , else inline-block drops down if not enough room */
}
```

basicly same answer as dartanian300 :)

You may control the max-width of `h1` too and add a `margin:auto;` : **[demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GDcag)**

Comment: `display: inline-block` should solve it along with a `width` in percentages. I mean in addition to the others provided in the answer.

Comment: Nevermind, this css does seem to work and keep the text centred :)

Comment: @misterManSam: Without the `inline-block`? Maybe then there are version differences probably. I am on Chrome 24 (duh :() and it moves the text to left aligned without the `inline-block`. `width` is not required though. Just noted that

Comment: @misterManSam it can be taking care of :) no width or max-width and margin:auto; http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GDcag regards

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Using `display: inline-block` simply removes the `h1` altogether on smaller screens.  You should avoid this.

Also, technically, the text is still centered.  It takes into account the ellipsis when centering the text.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

In order for the ellipsis styling to work, you've got to set a few things on the element with the text:

- `display: block;`
- `text-overflow: ellipsis;`
- `overflow: hidden;`
- `white-space: nowrap;`

`display: block` ensures that the box you're trying to generate ellipsis on is shown as a block.  If it's not, it won't know where the bounding box is.

`text-overflow: ellipsis` obviously should generate the ellipsis.

`overflow: hidden` for some reason, browsers won't generate the ellipsis unless you have this.  I believe it has to do with the fact that the text will just flow outside the box with it.

`white-space: nowrap` this prevents your text from wrapping onto multiple lines.  That way, you have one line with ellipsis at the end.

That work?

Comment: Embarrising. It actually worked. I think I looked after a much advanced solution when the simple way actually did it. Thanks!